# Erro na leitura do Like com o Timestampdiff

Tags: mysql

Bom Gente o Visual Studio não consegue ler a coluna Dias para fazer uma procura com o like e dá erro! Eu creio que ele lê o código de uma vez e não acha o Dias criado com o TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, Data_de_hoje, Data_do_compromisso).
Como eu poderia organizar o código acima para ele fazer umas pesquisa e mostrar o resultado sem dar erro?

```
"SELECT ID, Nome_do_cliente, Data_do_compromisso, Data_de_hoje,
  Data_do_cadastro, Data_de_hoje, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, Data_de_hoje, 
  Data_do_compromisso) AS Dias FROM agenda WHERE CONCAT(`Nome_do_cliente`, 
 `Data_do_compromisso`, `Data_de_hoje`, `Dias`)LIKE '%" + valorpesreb + "%'";
```

Mensagem de erro:

> Erro na leitura de dados! Unknown Column 'Dias' in Where Clause

Answer (score 0):

Você só pode usar apelidos de coluna em `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` ou `HAVING`.

> O padrão SQL não permite que você para se referir a um alias de coluna
>   em uma cláusula WHERE. Esta restrição é imposta porque quando o código
>   WHERE é executada, o valor da coluna pode ainda não ser determinado.
>
> <sub>Fonte: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html</sub>

Sendo assim, para resolver seu problemas teremos que duplicar a linha do `timestampdiff` no `where`, pois não podemos utilizar Alias. Fazendo o seguinte:

```
SELECT id
      ,nome_do_cliente
      ,data_do_compromisso
      ,data_do_cadastro
      ,data_de_hoje
      ,timestampdiff(DAY, data_de_hoje, data_do_compromisso) dias

  FROM agenda
 WHERE CONCAT(nome_do_cliente
             ,data_do_compromisso
             ,data_de_hoje
             ,timestampdiff(DAY, data_de_hoje, data_do_compromisso)) LIKE
              '%" + valorpesreb + "%';
```

Realizei o teste no [SQLFIndle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21ca85).

Comment: @Rafael, dessa forma não resolve seu problema?